# Returning an ArrayList of an object in rxAndroid

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I want to run a method periodically such that it returns an `ArrayList` of a custom object. Here is my code snippet,

```
    subscribe = Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(new Func1<Long, ArrayList<Item>>() {

                @Override
                public ArrayList<Item> call(Long aLong) {
                    return new ArrayList<Item>(aLong.intValue());
                }
            });
```

However, this gives an error

> `map(rx.functions.Func1<? super T, ? extends R>)`in Observable cannot be applied to `(anonymous rx.functions.Func1<java.lang.Long, java.util.ArrayList<com.example.Item>>)`

This works fine when the returned value is an `ArrayList<String>`. I do not understand what the problem is here. Are custom objects not allowed?

Comment: Your code looks fine. What is type of subscribe variable?

Comment: @jimmy0251 `rx.Subscription`

Comment: @jimmy0251 I got what the problem is, unless you do a complete `.subsribe()`, you do not have a `Subscription` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get subscription on map, you get it after subscribing. Here's sample code for demonstrating it.

```
  Observable<ArrayList<Item>> observable = Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(new Func1<Long, ArrayList<Item>>() {

                @Override
                public ArrayList<Item> call(Long aLong) {
                    return new ArrayList<Item>(aLong.intValue());
                }
            });
    Subscription subscription = observable.subscribe(new Action1<ArrayList<Item>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(ArrayList<Item> items) {
            //Do something with list items here
        }
    });
```